# How do you render an Angular 9 mat-table without a header row?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular9, mat-table

I'm using Angular 9.  How do I construct a mat-table without a header row (th) for the table?  Sounds silly but if I do this

```
<table mat-table *ngIf="isMobile" #mobile_table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="item">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item_stat">
      <div class="smallHeading">
        {{ item_stat.max_date }} m
      </div>
      <div class="mainRow divider">
        <a href="{{ item_stat.mobile_path }}">{{ item_stat.title }}</a> ·
        {{ getScore(item_stat) }}
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="mobileDisplayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: mobileDisplayedColumns;" [ngClass]="getRowClass(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

It produces the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
    at MatHeaderRowDef.extractCellTemplate (table.js:567)
    at table.js:2522
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at MatTable._getCellTemplates (table.js:2512)
    at MatTable._renderRow (table.js:2467)
    at table.js:2326
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MatTable._forceRenderHeaderRows (table.js:2321)
    at MatTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.js:1800)
    at callHook (core.js:4730)
```

I must add

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
```

to get the table to render properly.  This seems unnecessary as I don't want a header row for my table.  How do I build my mat-table so that this isn't required?

Comment: I don't think you can, but you can apply display: none to it

Answer (score 20):

You just need to remove the header line mat-header-row

```html
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="mobileDisplayedColumns"></tr>
```

It works fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

just delete the this line:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="mobileDisplayedColumns"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

Delete `<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>`

Or

on your css component add `:host ::ng-deep thead{display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-header-row {
  display: none;
}
```